# Adding value to a cell to the selected range of cells using GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to add the passed value to the function (say 20.35) to every selected cells. I have a huge list and the function below times out as far it can run upto 6 minutes without getting the added result to cells

How do I achive a workaround to write the cell everytime soon after completing the computation one after the other. For example if it expires after completing 10260 then upto 10259 the cell values are added with 20.35 which I can highlight by changing the color of cell at 1 to 10259. Those cells which original color means they arent added.

```
 function addToCells(isAll, valueToAdd) {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     if (isAll)
         var range = sheet.getDataRange();
     else
         var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

     var Values = range.getValues();

     for (var i in Values) {
         for (var j in Values[i]) {
             var value = Values[i][j].toString();
             if (value) {
                 Values[i][j] = parseFloat(value) + valueToAdd;
                 //how to write Values[i][j] to cell now
             }
         }
     }
     range.setValues(Values); // this will not execute if timesout

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is converting numbers to strings and back, which takes a lot more time than adding 1 to a number. I understand you want to avoid messing up strings with "1" at the end, and you probably don't want all empty cells to get "1" in them. Both are achieved by checking the type of an element before adding to it:

```
function testadd() {
  var range = ... // whatever
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValues = values.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(elem) {
      return (typeof elem == "number" ? elem + 1 : elem);
    });
  });
  range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

You do **not** want to run separate "setValue" for each cell, that would be a real performance killer and will likely leave you out of execution time quota pretty soon.

Comment: Appreciated, but this also results in timeout in my case as its quite large. Can you help me add and place the computed data intermittently instead placing at end.